# Adobe air: Navigate between .html pages?

Tags: html, apache-flex, adobe, air

I always thought of myself as being quite good at learning the most basic things with the help of Google and a cup of coffee, but when trying to get my head around basic Adobe AIR development, I have totally failed.

Apparently there's plenty of tutorials about loading data from local storage as well as remote places (Ajax), but I have yet not seen a clear instruction on how to navigate between the .html pages in the Applications directory.

Obviously `<a href="" />` isn't going to cut it, so my guess is that I need some DOM javascript magic to do it, which I yet not have seen.

**How can I navigate between** `.html` **pages in my applications directory properly?**

Thanks

Comment: I can't help but be a little confused.  The question is about Air, which by definition, is not hosted in the browser.  What HTML page are you trying to navigate?  Are you using the HTML control and trying to change the page on that?  Or is your terminology wrong, and you are actually referring to a Flex app hosted in the Flash player (in the browser)?

Comment: Hi! Sorry about being a little confusing in my description. I want to navigate to a html-page that's inside my application's folder.

Comment: So, you want to load an external browser? Or you want to embed the browser control in your app?  Can you give a code sample of what you are doing now, so we have a better idea?

Comment: Hi again! Nope - I just want to change from the <content>default.html</content> in initialwindow to another .html file, in the main AIR window if you understand me.

Comment: Yes, I understand now.  I will write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I understand what you are doing.  I hand't realized that an Air app can be an embedded HTML document with javascript hooks to the Air framework.  Pretty cool!  More information can be found here:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ecc.html

Anyways, since it is just HTML, all of the HTML rules apply.  I have a little "Hello World" app that uses both anchor navigation as well as javascript navigation:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Hello World</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="AIRAliases.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function appLoad(){ 
            air.trace("Hello World"); 
        }  
    </script> 
</head> 
<body onLoad="appLoad()"> 
    <h1>Hello World</h1> 
    <a href="AirHTML2.html">Go Next</a>
    <button onClick="location.href = './AirHTML2.html'">Go Next</button>
</body> 
</html>
```

In either case (clicking the link or clicking the button which calls `location.href`, I successfully navigate from one page to the next.

It didn't work for me at first, but that was because I wasn't packaging the second page with the application.  In my case, I just had to add the `AirHTML2.html` page to the `adt` packager, but I don't know how you are building your app... what environment are you using?

Anyways, it all seems pretty straight forward, actually. :)
[image: First Page]
[image: Second Page]

Comment: That's great! Worked directly for me - even in the `adl`, but had to use `<a href="app:/AirHTML2.html">Go Next</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTMLLoader class.

It has methods to go back and forward like you do with a regular browser.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html